# Call to a member function getClientOrginalName() on string

Tags: php, laravel

I cant upload file

> Error Call to a member function getClientOrginalName() on string

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $headers =new headerslider;

        $headers->text=$request->input('text');
        $headers->imgName = $request->input('imgName');

        if (request()->hasFile('imgName')){

            $headers =$request->file('imgName');
            $headers->store('images','public')->getClientOrginalName();
         }


        $headers->save();

        return redirect('admin/index');




    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `->getClientOrginalName();` after the store functionality

Laravel store functon returns the complete path of the file so you can do this

```php
$headers->text=$request->input('text');
$headers->imgName = $request->file('imgName')->getClientOriginalName(); // Here you can get the file name.

if (request()->hasFile('imgName')){
   $headers->image_path = request()->imgName->store('images','public');
   // $headers->image_path <--- this is dummy. just to give an example you can have the path of file 
}
$headers->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use that function as below:

```
$fileName = $request->file('imgName')->getClientOrginalName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this

First you have to get image name then where to store it

```
$headers->imgName = $request->input('imgName');

if (request()->hasFile('imgName')){

        $imageName = $request->file('imgName')->getClientOrginalName();
        $headers->imgName->storeAs('public/your_directory/',$imageName);
        $headers->imgName = $imageName;

}
```